# Find unique values in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a 3 column 200+ row section in my sheet.  These contain printer cartridge types.

What I need to do is get a single entry into a separate workbook of each entry in each row.

I have not used Excel in many years and have tried this:

```
=INDEX($D$3:$D$218, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($E$3:B218, $D$3:$E$218), 0))
```

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Having a hard time understanding what you want to achieve... could you reformulate or elaborate on "get a single entry into a separate workbook of each entry in each row" pls?

Comment: Sure.

I have 3 columns for colours of ink, in each row is a different type of cartridge, many of these are duplicates.  I now need somewhere else, anywhere; to have a new list with no duplicates from each column.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a formula here. Use remove duplicates function (Data -> Data tools -> Remove duplicates).